# How do I send a java object in a HTTP Request?

Tags: java, http

I am making a text game where it is necessary to upload a Object (Place) to a Java web server. (Players need to share data, however security is not a concern here) I am using the java.net.http APIs. My current method is

```
public void sendNewPlace(Place place) {
    HttpRequest.BodyPublisher publisher =
            HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofInputStream(() ->  {
                PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();

                ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
                    try (PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in)) {
                        return place;
                    }
                });

                return in;
            });
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:410/Places/Send/"))
            .POST(publisher)
            .build();
    try {
        client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e + ", please contact game admin.");
    }
}
```

But this throws `java.io.IOException: chunked transfer encoding, state: READING_LENGTH` on `client.send()`. I really have no clue what I should do to fix this, all the tutorials and StackOverflow questions either use a massive 3rd-party API, outdated code (pre-java 9), or want to send a String or int or something. Which are all very unhelpful. I am not super sure what this code does, I found it on a tutorial or question and modified it. I think I do not want to try to use JSON, and I was trying not to use 3rd-party libraries. In case you were wondering, my server code is as follows:

```
    public void makePlacesRecieveContext() {
        server.createContext("/Places/Send/", new HttpHandler() {
            public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("Hit! /Places/Send/");
                exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
                ObjectInputStream out = new ObjectInputStream(exchange.getRequestBody());
                try {
                    Place pl = (Place)out.readObject();
                    GetResponces.writeFile(new File("C://Users//programmerGuy//gameServer//Places//" + pl.getName()),pl);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                out.close();
                exchange.getRequestBody().close();
                System.out.println(exchange.getRemoteAddress().getHostName() + " : " + exchange.getRemoteAddress().getHostString());
            }
        });
    }
```

GetResponces is a class I built to handle most File IO. All I need to do is be able to upload these Place  objects to the server, my question is, how do I do that?

EDIT: My new client code is:

```
            public void sendNewPlace(Place place) {

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:410/Places/Send/"))
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(new Gson().toJson(place)))
            .build();
    try {
        client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e + ", please contact game admin.");
    }
}
```

In case the server side code has something to do with it,  here it is:

```
    public void makePlacesRecieveContext() {
    server.createContext("/Places/Send/", new HttpHandler() {
        public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Hit! /Places/Send/");
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
            String byteString = new String(exchange.getRequestBody().readAllBytes());
            Place p = new Gson().fromJson(byteString, Place.class);
            GetResponces.writeFile(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/webServer/places/" + p.getName() + ".place"), p);
            System.out.println(exchange.getRemoteAddress().getHostName() + " : " + exchange.getRemoteAddress().getHostString());
        }
    });
}
```

My error stayed the same for some reason... My client code is println-ing `Error: java.io.IOException: chunked transfer encoding, state: READING_LENGTH, please contact game admin.`

EDIT 3: The full error is as follows:
(I tried to use spoilers, I hope it worked)
java.io.IOException: chunked transfer encoding, state: READING_LENGTH
at
java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:565)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
at HttpClients.HttpPlaceClient.sendNewPlace(HttpPlaceClient.java:53)
at txtGame.Modules.makeNewPlace(Modules.java:117)
at txtGame.Player.(Player.java:38)
at txtGame.Main.(Main.java:16)
at txtGame.Main.main(Main.java:99)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: chunked transfer encoding, state: READING_LENGTH
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.Utils.wrapWithExtraDetail(Utils.java:294)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$BodyReader.onReadError(Http1Response.java:741)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1AsyncReceiver.checkForErrors(Http1AsyncReceiver.java:297)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1AsyncReceiver.flush(Http1AsyncReceiver.java:263)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: EOF reached while reading
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1AsyncReceiver$Http1TubeSubscriber.onComplete(Http1AsyncReceiver.java:591)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadSubscription.signalCompletion(SocketTube.java:632)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:833)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowTask.run(SocketTube.java:175)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.signalReadable(SocketTube.java:763)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent.signalEvent(SocketTube.java:941)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowEvent.handle(SocketTube.java:245)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:957)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.lambda$run$3(HttpClientImpl.java:912)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:912)

NOTE!!!: any help making this question shorter (possible with spoilers) would be greatly appreciated

Comment: use java serializate the class into json to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to make your **Place** class serializable, by

> implementing java.io.Serializable

Then the Place object needs to be converted to a json object, which can be done easily by using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) libraries.

Example using Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(placeObject);
```

Later while receiving the response you can deserialize it back to Place object using the same library.

```
Place placeObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, Place.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, is there any class that I don't have to download? I was hoping to keep the program as lightweight as possible... But if there isn't I will gladly use this.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but you have to manually parse the jsonString and set the values by constructing a new Place object. And also convert the Place object to a valid json string. But why to reinvent the wheel? This is a common practice to use a json formatting library. You can also check this http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/18/minimal-json-parser-for-java/
There is a performance comparison graph

Comment: Ok, I added the library to my code but I am still getting the same error: `java.io.IOException: chunked transfer encoding, state: READING_LENGTH`. I will post my code in the question.

Comment: If thats an encoding problem, you can specify in the request header. request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");